# Wit/location is messed up

Tags: location, entity, wit.ai, prebuild

I am working on an app in wit.ai where I'll use wit/location. Unfortunately the app seems to realize every unknown (or sometime pre trained) word as a wit/location:

1. here I trained several times:

[image]

2. I copy it again (after refreshing the page)

[image]

It is in Hungarian: helyszín means location, módosítása means change. But it happens with several other pre-trained sentence.

Can you please help me what is wrong? Maybe did I set up something wrong?

Comment: This happens to me as well I just let it be and on the backend ignore that entity when performing an a specific action

Comment: But it happens in front end as well. I set up a list of profanity and in the front end it recognizes one of them as a location which is super embarrassing.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but just do it from your side and manipulate the strings, do a replace or something to the list of profanity's in the text or something